How to fine tune relevance score using rank-feature in VESPA.AI
Context
I'm trying to improve the relevance score for the search results, i've couple of candidate profiles, i'm searching the best candidate profile based on the skills and role they play in the industry .
I've come up with Ranking profile and using that i'm searching for best relevant candidate . I'm using lexical + semantic both .
Challenge here is the vespa generated relevance score is not so great and i wanted to fine tune the ranking as well as relevance score .
Any heads-up on this would be really appreciated !.
Here I want To :
a. improve the relevance score for this profile.
b. bm25(skills) value is 0.0 in both matchfeatures and summaryfeature when actually it has both java and python .
Output :
{
  "root": {
    "id": "toplevel",
    "relevance": 1,
    "fields": {
      "totalCount": 143
    },
    "coverage": {
      "coverage": 100,
      "documents": 143,
      "full": true,
      "nodes": 1,
      "results": 1,
      "resultsFull": 1
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "id:candidate_profile:candidate_profile::a866fa7f-7e13-48fe-bdca-5a60a3198fd9",
        "relevance": 0.01639344262295082,
        "source": "candidate_profile",
        "fields": {
          "matchfeatures": {
            "bm25(profile_summary)": 5.470910610067547,
            "bm25(skills)": 0,
            "firstPhase": 0.8789145673605757,
            "nativeRank(profile_summary)": 0.08308099301928237,
            "semantic": 0.8789145673605757
          },
        "skills": [
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "Java Script",
            "React Js",
            "Python",
            "Web Designing",
            "Leadership",
            "Teamwork",
            "Observation",
            "Time management",
            "Communication",
            "Avid fitness enthusiast",
            "Volunteering",
            "Sports",
            "English",
            "Hindi"
          ],
        "summaryfeatures": {
            "bm25(latest_industry)": 0,
            "bm25(latest_job_title)": 0,
            "bm25(latest_role)": 0,
            "bm25(profile_summary)": 5.470910610067547,
            "bm25(skills)": 0,
            "embedding_sum": 55.06214759836439,
            "latest_industry_sum": 40.86598728704121,
            "latest_role_sum": 0,
            "skill_sum": 52.88688380786334,
            "vespa.summaryFeatures.cached": 0
          }
        }
    }
    ]
 }
}

Query I'm Running in Vespa DB :
"yql" : " select * from candidate_profile WHERE userQuery() or (all_role_title matches 'Software Developer') AND (skills matches 'python' OR skills matches 'java') AND (latest_role_title matches 'Senior Developer') or ({scoreThreshold:0.032 ,targetHits: 4}nearestNeighbor(embedding, e))",
"input.query(e)" : 'embed(e5, "query: Candidate who is working as Software Developer, Senior Developer has the following skills python, java.")',
"query": " Candidate who is working as Software Developer, Senior Developer has the following skills python, java.",
"ranking" : "common"

Ranking Profile Which I've created :
rank-profile common {
        weight skills : 500
        weight latest_role : 500
        weight latest_industry : 500
        weight latest_job_title : 400

        inputs {
            query(e) tensor<float>(x[384])
        }
        function semantic() {
            expression: max(0, cos(distance(field, embedding)))
        }
        function semantic_skills() {
            expression: max(0, cos(distance(field, skills_embedding)))
        }
        function semantic_latest_role() {
            expression: max(0, cos(distance(field, latest_role_embedding)))
        }
        function semantic_latest_job_title() {
            expression: max(0, cos(distance(field, latest_job_title_embedding)))
        }
        function semantic_latest_industry() {
            expression: max(0, cos(distance(field, latest_industry_embedding)))
        }
        function keyword_match(){
            expression: bm25(skills) + bm25(latest_role) + bm25(latest_industry) + bm25(latest_job_title)
        }
        first-phase {
            expression:  sum(keyword_match + semantic)
        }

        rank-properties {
            fieldMatch(skills).occurrenceImportance: 0.5
            fieldMatch(skills).proximityCompletenessImportance: 0.9
            bm25(skills).k1: 1.5
            bm25(skills).b: 0.85
            fieldMatch(profile_summary).occurrenceImportance: 0.5
            fieldMatch(profile_summary).proximityCompletenessImportance: 0.9
            bm25(profile_summary).k1: 1.5
            bm25(profile_summary).b: 0.85
        }

        summary-features: embedding_sum skill_sum latest_role_sum latest_industry_sum bm25(profile_summary) bm25(skills) bm25(latest_role) bm25(latest_industry) bm25(latest_job_title)

        function embedding_score() {
            expression: attribute(embedding) * query(e)
        }
        function embedding_sum() {
            expression: sum(embedding_score)
        }
        function skill_score(){
            expression : attribute(skills_embedding) * query(e)
        }
        function skill_sum(){
            expression : sum(skill_score)
        }
        function latest_role_score(){
            expression : attribute(latest_role_embedding)  * query(e)
        }
        function latest_role_sum(){
            expression : sum(latest_role_score)
        }
        function latest_industry_score(){
            expression : attribute(latest_industry_embedding) * query(e)
        }
        function latest_industry_sum(){
            expression : sum(latest_industry_score)
        }

        match-features {
            bm25(skills)
            bm25(profile_summary)
            nativeRank(profile_summary)
            semantic
            firstPhase
            
        }
        global-phase {
            expression {
            reciprocal_rank(semantic)
            }
        }
}


I was able to get the bm25(skills) score, also generated the score for other matching fields as well.
My Findings :

bm25 is a pure text ranking feature which operates over an indexed string field, in our case skills is an indexed fields but the type is array . So we changed the values to comma separated or change the type to string.
Reference : bm25

After first step you must use rank() operator in your query .


Query Sample :
"yql" : " select * from candidate_profile WHERE rank((all_role_title matches 'senior') AND (skills matches 'python' OR skills matches 'java') AND (latest_role_title matches 'developer') or ({targetHits: 40}nearestNeighbor(embedding, e)),userQuery())",
"input.query(e)" : 'embed(e5, "query: Candidate who is working as senior, developer has the following skills python, java.")',
"query": " Candidate who is working as senior, developer has the following skills python, java.",
"ranking" : "common"

Search Output :
{
  "root": {
    "id": "toplevel",
    "relevance": 1,
    "fields": {
      "totalCount": 40
    },
    "coverage": {
      "coverage": 100,
      "documents": 144,
      "full": true,
      "nodes": 1,
      "results": 1,
      "resultsFull": 1
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "id:candidate_profile:candidate_profile::85715181-73f9-4f61-9398-4e350e41e989",
        "relevance": 22.045853545320217,
        "source": "candidate_profile",
        "fields": {
          "matchfeatures": {
            "bm25(profile_summary)": 35.56386309994314,
            "bm25(skills)": 11.98552149345962,
            "firstPhase": 22.045853545320217,
            "semantic": 0.9177947832357726
          },
          "sddocname": "candidate_profile",
          "documentid": "id:candidate_profile:candidate_profile::85715181-73f9-4f61-9398-4e350e41e989",
          "first_name": "DEEPAK",
          "middle_name": "SINGH",
          "city": "Bengaluru",
          "gender": "Male",
          "skills": [
            "Java,Springboot,J2EE,Hibernet,AWS,C/C++,Core Java,Python Programming"
          ],
          "total_months_of_experience": 98,
          "candidate_type": "New_candidate",
          "languages": [
            "English",
            "Kannada",
            "Hindi",
            "Telugu"
          ],
          "has_own_vehicle": false,
          "profile_summary": "The candidate has an experience of 8.2 years and is working as Developer, Senior Developer and has the following skills Java,Springboot,J2EE,Hibernet,AWS,C/C++,Core Java,Python Programming in industries like Software.",
          "latest_organisation_name": "Flipkart",
          "latest_job_title": "Senior Developer",
          "latest_role": "Developer",
          "latest_industry": "Software",
          "latest_employment_type": "Permanent",
          "employment_history": [
            {
              "role": "Developer",
              "job_title": "Senior Developer",
              "employment_type": "Permanent",
              "is_current_job": 1,
              "industry": "Software",
              "organisation_name": "Flipkart"
            }
          ],
          "highest_education_level": "Not mentioned",
          "highest_course_is_full_time": false,
          "highest_course_is_highest_qualification": false,
          "financials": [
            {}
          ],
          "summaryfeatures": {
            "bm25(candidate_type)": 0,
            "bm25(highest_course_name)": 0,
            "bm25(highest_education_level)": 0,
            "bm25(highest_specialization)": 0,
            "bm25(languages)": 0,
            "bm25(latest_employment_type)": 0,
            "bm25(latest_industry)": 0,
            "bm25(latest_job_title)": 4.5712686343124105,
            "bm25(latest_role)": 4.5712686343124105,
            "bm25(profile_summary)": 35.56386309994314,
            "bm25(skills)": 11.98552149345962,
            "embedding_sum": 58.45279276280053,
            "latest_industry_sum": 48.31929411615329,
            "latest_role_sum": 51.93824407275679,
            "skill_sum": 52.75094562502136,
            "vespa.summaryFeatures.cached": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }


The reason bm25(skills) is 0 is that the query does not search the skills field: Match features are only populated for fields that are searched.
You can search it without impacting recall by using a RANK item in the query.
The rest - how do I get great relevance for my use case - is more suitable for a meeting.

That's weird to know that query is not searching skills field but instead it's brings  the profiles which has skills as python and java mentioned .
Let me know once you are free we can have a meeting on that.

I'll reach out on Slack :-)

I'm a search-engine datascientist and I worked on fine-tuning Vespa's ranking. Tell me if a misunderstood your problem xD
My feeling about your problem:

you should fine-tune your lexical and semantic approach separately
use ML / Learning to Rank (LTR) technics to improve the lexical part
you should fuse both approaches later using tools like reciprocal rank fusion or anything similar

TLDR: be patient and optimize your lexical ranking apart from the semantic one. This will not be an easy task but it is worth it (some people claim that semantic search is not enough and I agree).
fine tuning the lexical part
Ground truth data gathering
You must have some ground truth (GT) ranking data (namely "relevance judgements") to train a lexical ranking on it. See wiki. These are triplets made of:

query
document
relevance score
=> this expresses the fact that you know that some document has a certain relevance score regarding the given query. Gathering such kind of data is not an easy task and highly linked to your specific problem.

Usually you have several couples (doc, relevance) per query in this dataset.
Fetching features over GT data
Having some judgements, you must now know the lexical features Vespa would have computed on the documents while performing the GT's queries. To do so, I suggest building a specific rank-profile dedicated to your LTR problem and query Vespa with it. Your goal is to:

run a GT's query q1 on your Vespa instance
make sure somehow that the GT's docs (d_1, ..., d_k) associated to q1 are returned by your dedicated rank-profile, so you can access to the bunch of weak-signals computed by Vespa to measure each query/doc adequation. Example: bm25(skills), bm25(latest_job_title) as shown on your post
collect these weak-signals, join them with your known relevance
=> Doing this for all your GT's query will give you a ML/LTR dataset ready to be used for training.

Consider building another dedicated rank-profile to do negative sampling on your queries. This should give you random documents that are probably not very relevant to the query q1 and can be associated to zero-relevance in your dataset. This will give your LTR easy negative examples to train on.
Building such dedicated "tooling rank-profiles" can be a bit tricky but this is worth it. Hints: send the GT's document's id within the Vespa query, then use a direct id comparison in the rank-profile as score.
Use your collected data with LTR tool
Vespa is natively capable of handling several LTR models format (example in Vespa doc). You can use tools like  RAX and LightGBM in ranking mode to train on your LTR data.
Deploy your model on Vespa
The output is a model able to compute efficiently a data-driven lexical ranking score based on the raw Vespa weak-signals. Vespa is able to use this score in a new rank-profile very easily. Using this rank-profile inheriting from your data-driven model provides you a way of "mimicking" (actually since it is ML, it is rather generalization) the relevance judgements of your LTR dataset.
Semantic part
Just pick a nice embedding model like Matryoshka Representation Learning (see Vespa blog post).
Fuse the best of both worlds
Use Vespa tools like Reciprocal Rank Fusion to fuse your optimized lexical ranking and your well chosen semantic.
